# Pagination Nodejs express with mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, api, express

I'm using node.js express with mysql. I want to make pagination with 10 articles per page. In my node.js api, I've made model and route. These are my model and route.

This is Model News.js:

```
var db = require('../db');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');    
var Task = {
    getNews: function(callback){
        sql ="select * from t_article"+
             " where publish='Y'"+
             " order by date DESC"
        return db.query(sql,callback);
    },
    getNewsLimit: function(limit,callback){
        sql2 ="select * from t_article"+
         " where publish='Y'"+
         " order by date DESC LIMIT ? "
    ar2 = [limit]
        return db.query(sql2,parseInt([ar2]),callback)
    }
};
module.exports=Task;
```

And this is for 
Route News.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var router = express.Router();
var app = express();
var Task = require('../models/News');    
router.get('/api/:limit?',function(req,res,next){

    if(req.query.limit){
        // var dateFormat = new Date(Date.UTC(req.params.year,req.params.day-1,req.params.month,0,0));

        Task.getNewsLimit(req.query.limit,function(err,rows){

            if(err)
            {
                res.json(err);
            }
            else{

                 res.json(rows);
            }
        });
     }
    else{
        Task.getNews(function(err,rows){
            if(err)
            {    
                res.json(err);
            }
            else{    
                 res.json(rows)
            }
        });
   }
});
module.exports=router;
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: @Cid make pagination, show 10 articles per page

Answer (score 1):

Hey If you want to do do `req.query` then you put limit like this
`'/api/?limit=pagelimit` this will help req.query pick the value you put at the after an equal sign